# Build a specific list of string from a string in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm starting learning haskell and i'm stuck in a problem.

I read from the standard input a string like `"1234"` or `"azer"` 
and I want to make a list like `["123", "234", "341", "412"]` or `["aze", "zer", "era", "raz"]`.

I probably must use `map` but i don't know how to proceed.
Is someone can help me to do that ? Thanks

Comment: Concatenate the string with itself and output chunks of three, advancing the beginning by one each time.

Comment: `\xs -> zipWith (const (take 3)) xs (tails (cycle xs))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a list, `[1..4]`. Let's repeat it for eternity:

```
>>> cycle [1..4]
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...
```

Now let's take a slice of it, at say, the 2nd index:

```
>>> take 4 $ drop (2-1) $ cycle [1..4]
[2,3,4,1]
```

We can generalize this by naming a function:

```
slice n = take 4 $ drop n $ cycle [1..4]
```

To obtain all possible cyclic permutations, we only need to sample n from 1 to 4:

```
>>> map slice [1..4]
[[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
```

---

Now, how can we make this work with an arbitrary string? Let's redefine slice to accept a string:

```
slice s n = take (length s) $ drop n $ cycle s
```

And so our cyclic permutations function can be defined as follows:

```
cyclicPerms s = map (slice s) [1..(length s)]
```

Testing:

```
>>> cyclicPerms "abcde"
["bcdea","cdeab","deabc","eabcd","abcde"]
```

Comment: Works great, thanks you! I added map (take n) (cyclicPerms s) to make this with an arbitrary number to take only the n firsts caracters

Answer (score 0):

I had originally posted an answer totally misunderstanding the specification. I, like a Haskell enumeration, read only the first two numbers so I thought it continued as such. Oops. In any event I just adapted a `chunks` function I wrote to produce the repetitions. When I get home, I think I have another that cycles lists. I'll post it as well if it's not the same. Who knows.

This function allows you to specify the chunk size as well as the list.

```
cychnks n ls = [take n.drop x$ls2|(x,y) <-zip [0..] ls]
                where ls2 = ls++ls

cychnks 5 "abcde"
```

["abcde","bcdea","cdeab","deabc","eabcd"]

```
cychnks 3 "abcde"
```

["abc","bcd","cde","dea","eab"]